# Converting Data to string gets nil value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a project in which I have to store image into sqlite database. but when I try to convert NSData to NSString It returns nil value.

Here is my code.

```
    imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img_userprofile.image).bytes length:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img_userprofile.image).length];
    NSString *charlieSendString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Friends values(null, '%@', '%@', '%@')", self.txt_name.text,charlieSendString, self.txt_mobile_no.text ];
    [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];

        // If the query was successfully executed then pop the view controller.

    if (self.dbManager.affectedRows != 0) {
       NSLog(@"Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = %d", self.dbManager.affectedRows);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Could not execute the query.");
    }
```

Help me thank you

Comment: just check the data is inserted into the database of not before fetch ..

Comment: I am inserting data through query. So if data is not there how can I fetch it?

Comment: probably your data is not residing inside db just double check it or something wrong with your string containing image data.

Comment: Yeah why store a string as data given sqlite3 can handle UTF-8?

Comment: How can you imagine between 2 line that something is wrong? Imagedata returns data properly and in next line it didnt convert into string. How can i find problem ?

Comment: You should be using bind variables and prepared statements, not constructing insert statements using strings.

Comment: perhaps you should imagine what prob it cound be and i don't know why storing your imagedata to string, in fact you can directly send `imageData` inside the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img_userprofile.image).bytes length:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img_userprofile.image).length];
NSString *strEncodeImg = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

We have download Base64 library from this link : https://github.com/bborbe/base64-ios/tree/master/Base64

Comment: Base64 encoding is supported by `NSData` directly, no need to download a third party library.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just assume that the binary data representing a PNG image is also a valid UTF-8 encoding of a string, which is what your code is doing in the first 2 lines.

You are getting null because the binary data cannot be interpreted as a UTF-8 string.

What you need to do is to use a string encoding of the binary data, base64 is common and also supported directly by `NSData`. Lookup up the `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` method to generate the string, and `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` for converting an encoded string back to data.

HTH

Comment: What is wrong with storing the binary data in the database; why does it need to be base-64 encoded?

Comment: @Droppy - nothing wrong if the database supports it. The answer simply addresses the issue the OP was having converting binary data to a string.

Comment: Agreed; however encouraging the use of base-64 where it's not required is very inefficient and the OP's issue is really that he's misusing the sqlite API.

Comment: your Suggestion is Also working successfully. Thanks so much

Comment: Can U give me Demo, So I can implement it. Please

Comment: @Jecky - So something obviously went wrong between your two comments.  Ask a new question showing the code you wrote using `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` and `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` and explain the problem you encountered. However also note the other comments suggesting you should really store your image data as binary in the DB.

Comment: @CRD I have done this thing but now my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995156/memory-increase-while-retriving-data-from-database-for-loading-image