# Memory increase when loading image with encoded data

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am working in project in which I store string of image data to database by using this library https://github.com/bborbe/base64-ios/tree/master/Base64.

So when I get that image field I decode that data and shows image

My code to encode Image data

```
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img_user_profile.image, 0.4);;
 NSString *strEncodeImg = [Base64 encode:imageData];
```

My code to decode image data

```
NSData *str = [Base64 decode:[[arr_user_info valueForKey:@"image"] objectAtIndex:0]];
_img_user.image =[UIImage imageWithData:str];
```

My problem is **When I get data string from database and load image in imageview, Memory increases with every image**.

Please help me with it

Comment: Try storing the image as data, not base-64, as this will mean you don't need to encode and decode to base-64.  Learn to use sqlite prepared statements and bind variables.  You have made shortcuts and are now paying for it (I refer you to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955237/converting-data-to-string-gets-nil-value)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the attribute as NSString you can declared that as NSData. Now you can directly store the imageData into core data. When fetching you can use imageData directly to load the image