# Memory Increase while Retriving data from database for loading image

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, decoding

I am working on application in which I store data of image into database like

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Friends_user (f_id,f_name,f_image,f_mobile) VALUES('%ld','%@','%@','%@')",(long)id_, self.txt_name.text,[UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.img_userprofile.image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength], self.txt_mobile_no.text ];
```

It stores Successfully but when I retrieve that data to display image, Memory Increases with every image. Here is my code to retrieve data

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:[[arr_friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2] options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    img_friend_profile.image= [UIImage imageWithData:data];

[theAppDelegate.dbManager executeQuery:query];
```

My Datatype in database is BLOB.
Memory increases Upto 10-20 MB per image. Please Help me with it

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you save the images to the documents directory and keep the path of the new image in the database?

Comment: Yeah, I can do. but solving my problem can solve problem of too many others. Please If you have solution then post it

Comment: To the best of my understanding of how UIImage works, it creates an uncompressed representation of an image in a memory cache for rendering and, if there is memory pressure, the cache is purged. My hunch is that, because there is no file in the file system for UIImage to "fall back" to, that cache stays in memory indefinitely.

If that is the case, one way to solve the issue would be to create temporary files with image data and use them to create UIImage instances.